# Change application from Framework 4.6 to 4.0 and SchemaComparison stop working

Tags: c#, frameworks

I'm trying to pass from framework 4.6 to 4.0.
    I'm using SchemaDacpac for copy schema tables from a file .dacpac to an existing database in SQL server.
    The problem is that now this line of code give me an `nullPointerException` due to reading .scmp file that contains the options for the comparison between the file and de SQL database.

Now what i'm doing is this:

```
SchemaComparison schemaComparison = new SchemaComparison(pathToFile);
```

I have to read the comparison from a file because I have generated the file previously (and it work) with:

```
SchemaComparison schemaComparison = new SchemaComparison(sourceDacpac, targetDatabase);
```

But i need to take the file generated and generate another file. I tried with other variables or doing the same thing in other parts of the program but the result was the same...
    For me the problem is the reading from the file.

```
ModelTypeClass modelTypeClass;
ModelTypeClass childrenModelTypeClass;
String esitoPubblicazione = "Pubblicazione fallita!";
SchemaCompareDacpacEndpoint sourceDacpac = null;
SchemaComparison comparison = null;
SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint targetDatabase = null;
var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
string erroriPubblicazione = "";
bool bTrovataTabellaDaEscludere = false;
bool ritorno = true;
bool esistenzaDB = false;
//carico il dacpac di release dal quale prendere le modifiche che dovrò fare sul database di destinazione
//questo può essere caricato o direttamente dal txt del file oppure dal file txt che viene passato
//quindi controllo se il valore nell'array dei parametri connDB all'ultima posizione c'è, se c'è non prendo 
//quello nel txt, altrimenti si.
if (pathDacPac != "" && pathDacPac != null)
{
    sourceDacpac = new SchemaCompareDacpacEndpoint(pathDacPac);
}
else
{
        MessageBox.Show("Il percorso del dacpac non è valido.");
        ritorno = false;           
}

//questa stringa la riempio con i valori dei txt sempre, solo che nel caso in cui leggo da file prima riempio gli stessi txt con i valori nel file
csb.DataSource = dataSource;
csb.UserID = userID;
csb.Password = password;
csb.InitialCatalog = InitialCatalog;
csb.IntegratedSecurity = false;

targetDatabase = new SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint(csb.ToString());
if (sourceDacpac != null && targetDatabase != null)
{
    comparison = new SchemaComparison(sourceDacpac, targetDatabase);
    //testo la connessione, se non c'è il database che sto cercando allora avviso l'utente ed esco
    esistenzaDB = testConnessione(csb);
    if (esistenzaDB == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

                //creo un array object dove specifico gli oggetti che devono essere portati nel database di destinazione
    ObjectType[] otDoNotDrop = new ObjectType[10];
    otDoNotDrop.SetValue(ObjectType.DatabaseTriggers, 0);
    otDoNotDrop.SetValue(ObjectType.Views, 1);
    otDoNotDrop.SetValue(ObjectType.MasterKeys, 2);
    otDoNotDrop.SetValue(ObjectType.ColumnMasterKeys, 3);
    otDoNotDrop.SetValue(ObjectType.DatabaseEncryptionKeys, 4);

     //se ci sono degli oggetti da escludere allora riempio anche l'array delle esclusioni e lo setto
     //ObjectType[] otExclusions = new ObjectType[10];
     //comparison.Options.ExcludeObjectTypes = otExclusions;   

     comparison.Options.DoNotDropObjectTypes = otDoNotDrop;

     if (effettuaBackup == "SI")
     {
         comparison.Options.BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges = true;
     }

     comparison.Options.BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false; //non blocco l'esecuzione se c'è una perdita di dati

     //il file non prende la password, allora prendo il testo del file e sostituisco la parte della connessione al db
     //e aggiungo la password
     //if (Directory.Exists(percorsoDefault) == false)
     //{
     //    Directory.CreateDirectory(percorsoDefault);
     //}
     comparison.SaveToFile(@"C:\RELEASE\PROVA_ALLINEADB\mycomparison.scmp");

     string testoFile = File.ReadAllText(percorsoDefault + "mycomparison.scmp");
    testoFile = testoFile.Replace("<ConnectionString>Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + InitialCatalog + ";Integrated Security=False" + ";User ID=" + userID + ";Pooling=False</ConnectionString>", "<ConnectionString>" + "Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + InitialCatalog + ";Integrated Security=False" + ";User ID=" + userID + ";Password=" + password + ";Pooling=False</ConnectionString>");
    File.WriteAllText(percorsoDefault + "mycomparison.scmp", testoFile);
    // carico il file .scmp per la comparazione
    SchemaComparison schemaComparison = new SchemaComparison(@"C:\RELEASE\PROVA_ALLINEADB\mycomparison.scmp");
}
```

The exception is: "`System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance.'`" Because the reading (in the last line of the code) from the file fails.

Do you know any other solutions to do the same thing but in 4.0 framework?

Comment: Downgrading your framework version can always be problematic.  Have you updated the references you use here (for the schemacomparison) to ones compatible with this framework?

Comment: Yes i did, but maybe some components that are able on library version x.x.6 are not present in the library x.x.5 but for now i solved the problem by holding the framework 4.6 on the project and downloading the 4.8 framework from Microsoft site. Luckily this "framework4.8.exe"  allowed me to install it on windows server 2008 and to launch my executable, so for now it's ok! Thank you!! if anyone knew the answer i'm listening, could come back handy!!